# Using strpos to identify UPDATE or INSERT query: not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

The code below receives a query and may only execute it when the query contains 'INSERT' or 'UPDATE'. But when I feed it 'INSERT INTO test_table (id, test_value) VALUES (1, 'Test')', it raises the 'requires an Update or Insert query'.

What am I missing?

```
    public function setQuery($query)
{                
    if(strpos($query, 'INSERT') === false && strpos($query, 'UPDATE') === false ) {
                trigger_error('Method [' . __FUNCTION__ . '] requires an Update or Insert query [Q: '.$query.']');
                exit;
            }

    $this->_queries++;                
    mysql_query($query);
    $this->_result = mysql_insert_id();

    if(!$this->_result) {
                trigger_error('Method [' . __FUNCTION__ . '] failed [Q: '.$query.']');
    }                
    return $this->_result;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do use strpos against `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 'INSERT'`?

Comment: Nothing much, really. At least nothing harmfull. The function is not open to user input. The query is executed but no result is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe someone send you 'insert'? Try stripos :)

Comment: Nope. I've been the only one to send the function any parameters and I'm absolutely sure it was 'INSERT', not 'insert'. Strange though: I've replaces strpos with stripos, and now it works. Really beats me... Thanks for your help (and symcbean too!)

Answer (score 1):

It works when I try it using the parameter you provided.

(BTW it'll be a bit more robust if you use stripos)

Can't tell you why its not working for you.

C.